# HOw remove counter from Jquerymobile multiple select button

Tags: jquery-mobile

In multiple select ,once 2+ items are selected, a counter element with the total number of selected items will appear inside the button.
How to remove the counter element from the button

Answer (score 1):

Old question to answer. Though, here what i do to hide it. Applied this CSS -

```
.ui-select .ui-li-count{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should to the Multiple selects in Jqmobile...

Download Jqmobile and Open documentation and refer to that...

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/forms/selects/custom.html